# Get the ID of category page with or without any posts

Tags: terms

Is there a better way to get the category ID that may or may not have any posts assigned to it?

Currently im using the following code that resorts to parsing the page url, and getting the category ID from its slug. Doesn't feel like the best way to do it.

```
$current_url = rtrim($_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], "/");
$arr_current_url = split("/", $current_url);
$thecategory = get_category_by_slug( end($arr_current_url) );
$catid = $thecategory->term_id;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of [`get_queried_object_id()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_queried_object_id/) in your category page. This will return the ID of the category.

This is really useful little function. It will return the the:

- author ID on an author archive page
- term ID on a taxonomy, tag and category archive pages
- post ID on a single post page
- page ID of a page

### EDIT

From your answer, you can simplify your code to something like this

```
if ( is_category() ) {

    $catid = get_queried_object_id();

} elseif ( is_single() ) {

    $cats = wp_get_post_terms( get_queried_object_id(), 'category', array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) ); // category object
    $catid = $cats[0];
}
```

The above code is faster and is more reliable :-)

Comment: Thank you Pieter, the issue with `get_queried_object` is that it won't have the same output for every situation. This is, I need get the same ID no matter Im in a category page or on a post of that category.

Comment: Please file an edit and explain exactly what are your requirements. A single post don't have a category returned in `get_queried_object()`. You can only get the category like `get_the_category()` or `wp_get_post_terms()` on a single post page.

Comment: I ended up using a different query to verify the topmost category for category and post pages. Thank you for the tips.

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this is by checking if we are on a category page or single post:

```
if ( is_category() ) {

    $current_url = rtrim($_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], "/");
    $arr_current_url = split("/", $current_url);
    $catid = get_category_by_slug( end($arr_current_url) );

} elseif ( is_single() ) {

    $cats = get_the_category(); // category object
    $postcat = end($cats);
    $catid = $cats;
}
```

For the category we are parsing the URL and retrieving the category ID from its slug.

In a single post we simply use the `get_the_category` core function to retrieve an object with the categories associated to the post, from which we retrieve the last one.

**EDIT:**
Taking Pieter's code, I just had to make a minor adjustment to select the last category associated with the post (Im assuming it's the deepest), otherwise works flawlessly.

```
 if ( is_category() ) {

    $catid = get_queried_object_id();

} elseif ( is_single() ) {

    $cats = wp_get_post_terms( get_queried_object_id(), 'category', array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) ); // category object
    $catid = end($cats);

}
```

Comment: Please see my edit on how to optimize your code. As it stands, your code is not very reliable and much slower that my updated code :-)

Comment: Just for interest sake and for extra info ( no need to use this, your method is fine :-)), you can also sort your post terms in wp_get_post_terms() by id in descending order and still get the first id from the array. Check the codex and the third parameter for wp_get_post_terms. :-)